# Creating a 2x2 Button Grid with Centered Buttons?

Tags: layout, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have a 2x2 button grid.  Now I'd like to shrink the buttons to
200x200, place each in a container as a space place holder, then center
each button in its respective container.

In my image, I've only
shrunk the two top buttons so you can see the spacing on the page.
How can I go from the first image to the second image, which was
Photoshop'ed?

[image]

The goal: (actually, all 4 centered buttons is the goal)
[image]

File: app.js

```
Ext.application({

    launch: function() {
        var view = Ext.create('Ext.Container', {
            layout: {
                type: 'vbox'
            },
            items: [
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    flex: 1,
                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            flex: 1,
                            items:[
                                {
                                    xtype:'button',
                                    text: 'Home',
                                    ui: 'plain',
                                    style: 'background-color: #c9c9c9',
                                    height: 200,
                                    width: 200
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        {
                            xtype: 'container',
                            layout: 'hbox',
                            flex: 1,
                            items:[
                                {
                                    xtype:'button',
                                    text: 'News',
                                    ui: 'plain',
                                    style: 'background-color: #b9b9cb',
                                    height: 200,
                                    width: 200
                                }
                             ]
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    xtype: 'container',
                    layout: 'hbox',
                    flex: 1,
                    items:[
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            text: 'Mail',
                            ui: 'plain',
                            style: 'background-color: #a9c9c9',
                            flex: 1
                        },
                        {
                            xtype:'button',
                            text: 'Search',
                            ui: 'Search',
                            style: 'background-color: #c9c9c9',
                            flex: 1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        });
        Ext.Viewport.add(view);
    }
});
```

File: index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="" lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Sencha</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://extjs.cachefly.net/touch/sencha-touch-2.0.0/resources/css/sencha-touch.css" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://extjs.cachefly.net/touch/sencha-touch-2.0.0/sencha-touch-all-debug.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply add `centered:true` to the configuration of all your buttons.

Good luck.

P/S: that config actually set your component to the center (horizontally & vertically) of its **parent** component.